# Should a websocket connection be general or specific?

Tags: websocket

Should a websocket connection be general or specific?

e.g. If I was building a stock trading system, I'd likely to have real time stock prices, real time trade information, real time updates to the order book, perhaps real time chat to enable traders to collude and manipulate the market. Should I have one websocket to handle all the above data flow or is it better to have several websocket to handle different topics?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends. Let's look at your options, assuming your stock trader, your chat, and your order book are built as separate servers/micro-services.

#### One WebSocket for each server

You can have each server running their own WebSocket server, streaming events relevant to that server.

**Pros**
It is a simple approach. Each server is independent.

**Cons**
Scales poorly. The number of open TCP connections will come at a price as the number of concurrent users increases. Increased complexity when you need to replicate the servers for redundancy, as all replicas needs to broadcast the same events. You also have to build your own fallback for recovering from client data going stale due to lost WebSocket connection. Need to create event handlers on the client for each type of event. Might have to add version handling to prevent data races if initial data is fetched over HTTP, while events are sent on the separate WebSocket connection.

#### Publish/Subscribe event streaming

There are many publish/subscribe solutions available, such as [Pusher](https://pusher.com/), [PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/) or [SocketCluster](https://stackshare.io/socketcluster). The idea is often that your servers publish events on a topic/subject to a message queue, which is listened to by WebSocket servers that forwards the events to the connected clients.

**Pros**
Scales more easily. The server only needs to send one message, while you can add more WebSocket servers as the number of concurrent users increases.

**Cons**
You most likely still have to handle recovery from events lost during disconnect. Still might require versioning to handle data races. And still need to write handlers for each type of event.

#### Realtime API gateway

This part is more shameless, as it covers [Resgate](https://github.com/jirenius/resgate), an open source project I've been involved in myself. But it also applies to solutions such as [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/). With the term "realtime API gateway", I mean an *API gateway* that not only handles HTTP requests, but operates bidirectionally over WebSocket as well.

With web clients, you are seldom interested in events - you are interested in change of state. Events are just means to either describe the changes. By fetching the data through a gateway, it can keep track on which resources the client is currently interested in. It will then keep the client up to date for as long as the data is being used.

**Pros**
Scales well. Client requires no custom code for event handling, as the system updates the client data for you. Handles recovery from lost connections. No data races. Simple to work with.

**Cons**
Primarily for client rendered web sites (using React, Vue, Angular, etc), as it works poorly with sites with server-rendered pages. Harder to apply to already existing HTTP API's.